# Can strings be used in a ternary conditional statement?

Tags: java, string, char, conditional-statements, ternary

I'm (very) new to Java and have been using Codecademy, and after learning about ternary conditionals I was wondering if a string could be used in place of char? I know that strings aren't a real primitive data type in Java whereas char is, but it seems like you should be able to print out a string rather than a single character without having to use if/else statements or something similar.

```
//my ternary with char
public class dogBreeds
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int dogType = 2;
       char dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? 'Y':'N';
   }
}

//my ternary with string (or something like it) in place of char
public class dogBreeds
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int dogType = 2;
      String dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? 'Yes':'No';
   }
}
```

Comment: Use double quotes for strings. Strings are immutable.

Comment: This is also a case where you should use an `enum DogType` instead of a magic int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When representing `String`s, use double quotes as they signify a string literal. Single quotes signify a `char` literal:

```
String dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

There are differences with `String` and `char` types. Strings are immutable and cannot be changed after they are created. When a `String` object is created and the constructor is called, it can't be changed. If you want to use `String`s, consider `StringBuilder` if you want it to be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
String dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? "Yes": "No";
```

Comment: I thought wombats were afraid of dogs :-P

Comment: Scary Wombats ain't scared of nuffin

Comment: They are scary, I'll give you that :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
String dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? "Yes":"No";
```

Strings are enclosed using `double quotes` where are character is mentioned with in `single quotes`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo..
When you do this

```
String dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? 'Yes': 'No';
```

You are using the char sign  (single quotes ), it must be done with double quotes. . Like:

```
String dalmation = (dogType == 2) ? "Yes": "No";
```